# Secure Connection Failed using Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-connection, firefox-extensions

I'm using Firefox 5 with some add-ons that require an external connection to a certain server (lastPass & Xmarks). I'm using the connection from my company, and every once in a while I get the following popup:

> Secure connection failed.
>
> This certificate in not trusted
>   because the certificate issuer isn't
>   trusted.
>
> (Error code:
>   sec_error_untrusted_issuer)

This also occurs using other versions of Firefox.

Comment: Is your company connection using a proxy server?

Comment: No. Which is really weird. But I've to use a username & password to use it when I launch the browser.

Comment: That sounds like a "walled garden".  In that case, there could still be a proxy server that isn't visible from your end.  If that's the case, and there's an issue with the way the proxy handles SSL, it could cause this error.  Try to visit https sites until you get an error stating that the certificate is not signed by a secure source, then check the issuer listed on that certificate.

Comment: And do what if I find the issuer?

Comment: See if the issuer is valid.  You might see Verisign or another well-known certificate authority.  If you see your company's name instead, or a servername that matches your company's naming practices (such as proxy1.company.com), then it could be a misconfigured SSL proxy somewhere on the network.

Comment: The issuer isn't valid, I viewed the certificate and exported it. Then imported it again using the certificates manager and "trusted" it. It solved the problem temporary (for one complete session) When I opened firefox again it started all over again although the certificates are still there